# Did Bran Stark actually do anything as a warg in the final battle with the White Walkers?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Bran told Theon he'd be going then warged into a few crows. What did he accomplish as the crow?  It didn't look like he posed any  threat to the Night's King. And if it was reconnaissance he didn't debrief with anyone about what he saw.

What was the strategy there?

Comment: I think this question is actually a lot more specific than the supposed "duplicate" question.  It is asking about a very specific thing that Bran did - warg into crows - and what the purpose of that specific thing was.  The linked question, on the other hand, is more broad - and does not address Bran doing this, either in the question or within the given answers.

Comment: @MishaR true so I cast the final reopen vote. However it is a duplicate of another question that is the same so reclosed!